# does "new XML(...)" throws a typeError if the input is not an xml

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have code as below:

```
 var s : String = "hello world"
 var xml : XML;
 try {
    xml = new XML(s);
 } catch (e:TypeError) {
    trace("get a typeError");
 }
```

but I don't see it gets into the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XML()` accepts anything (`*`) in its constructor:

```
XML(value:* = null)
```

So no, it does not throw a `TypeError`.

Note you don't actually need to use the `new` keyword for creating instances of `XML`:

```
var xml:XML = <item>Content</item>;
```

---

This may also be of interest for you - from [`XML()` - Top level function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#XML%28%29):

> `XML()`
>   Converts an object to an `XML` object.
>   The following table describes return values for various input types.
>   [image]

Comment: Thank Marty, so how can I tell whether the input is right or not? I load an xml using URLLoader. I expect to load in an xml but sometimes it loads in a html instead. How can I tell whether what is loaded is an xml?

Comment: @Vicky I believe that "HTML" will simply be interpreted as XML and there isn't a way to differentiate between them automatically.

Comment: That is, unless it's strict html. There might be unclosed tags such as `<br>` or incorrectly nested tags in the html code, which would probably ruin the xml object in ActionScript.